# Is there any method in web3js library to know if a given address is a contract address or an wallet's account address?

Tags: web3js, solidity-0.8.x, mocha, smart-contract

I am writing solidity tests . I am using JS for testing . Is there any method in web3js library to know that a certain address is a contract's address or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getCode` function as below [REFERENCE](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.2/web3-eth.html#getcode)

```js
const code = await web3.eth.getCode("0xd5677cf67b5aa051bb40496e68ad359eb97cfbf8");
//check If the address is a contract address
const IsAContractAddress = !!(code?.length > 0) 
// check If the address is an Externally owned account
const IsEOA= !(code?.length > 0)
```

If there is a code(length >0 ), it ensures that it is an contract address.